# Which CMS can build a website that needs reviews for profiles?

Tags: website, wordpress, drupal, cms, saas

I was investigating Drupal and WordPress, and I can't get them to do what I really want.

I'm trying to create essentially just a database of users that can login with their social media accounts, and their profiles on the website all have a user rating generated by other users rating them for their activity, and I want that to be visible when the profile of the person is viewed like "John has 4.4/5 stars and has been rated 473 times" - that's exactly that I'm looking for.

All the plugins and widgets in Drupal and WordPress that I've come across, don't really have or do what I need. This is simply a site used to upload media and get rated for it. Not for the media, but the quality of your profile.

I was looking at IPB, but the cost is insane for something so simplistic, however I think it would do what I want. But only on the newer versions which are pricey, 2.0.0 was the last free version and I doubt it would support some of the things I would require

Does anyone have an idea of a CMS or Message Board Platform that would have these simplistic features?

Account creation via social media connection, and a profile/user rating system? Everything else I need done is just strictly easy HTML and PHP coding I'd have to edit together, but I'm having the hardest time finding the right too for the rating system

Any guidance?

If this can be done with WordPress, and there's just some widgets or plugins that I don't know about, please point me in their direction!

Answer (score 1):

> If this can be done with <strike>Wordpress</strike> **Drupal**, and there's just some widgets or plugins that I don't know about, please point me in their direction!

If Drupal also (still) qualifies and if you're looking for a working module example with user voting, ratings and statistics, you may want to have a look at the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (which enables the content types **Question** and **Answer**, whereas Answers are displayed below the Question they relate to). Together with (at least) 2 of its submodules, i.e.:

- ***Answers Voting***, to implement a system to upvote or downvote either Questions and/or Answers (which uses the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module).
- ***Answers Userpoints***, to increase or decrease "*reputation points*" (which uses the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module) on events such as up- or down-voting on a question or answer, or marking an Answer as the "*Best Answer*".

Head over to its project page for more details.

To extract nodes related statistics, just use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, similar to what is shown on the [Answers demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) (in read only mode for anonymous users). It includes [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) based lists of:

- [Questions](http://drupal.placeto.be/questions).
- [Answers](http://drupal.placeto.be/answers).
- [Rankings](http://drupal.placeto.be/answers/rankings/reputation) (reputation based).

Quite a lot of the "business logic" of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module is implemented via all sorts of configurable rules (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module). As an example, if you don't agree with the out-of-the-box rules about how much "userpoints" are granted to an upvoted (or downvoted) question (or answer), you just use the Rules UI to tune the amount of such points to your requirements.

So with the above in mind, and to make this concept work for you, here are some minor tweaks to fit your case:

- To implement what you described as "profiles" could be done using the "question" content type (just label it something like "portofolio", or whatever you want). And have each user create 1 node which they can "*use to upload media*" (use the power of Drupal to add any relevant fields, etc to fit your needs).
- No sure if you want other users to be able to post "answers" to such "questions". If that's the case, just disable the answers content type. As an alternative, use that "answers" content type for (eg) writing reviews about the portfolio.

After you finished the implementation as per my suggestions above, you may end up with a ranking similar to [this demo sample](http://drupal.placeto.be/answers/rankings/reputation).

Last but not least, the cost for this should NOT be insane (for something so simplistic), mostly because it's all Drupal based, and you just need the skills (or hire someone with such skills) to get it configured.

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module.